# Problem with public bool function in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a problem with my public bool variable. Here is my code

`Death` script (placed on a left to right moving block)

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class death : MonoBehaviour 
{
    IEnumerator Wait()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
        SceneManager.LoadScene("level 4");
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider col) 
    {
        if(col.name == "Sphere") 
        {   
            player_script.IsPlaying = false;
            StartCoroutine(Wait());
        }      
    }
}
```

Player script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class player_script : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float velocity = 5f;
    public bool IsPlaying = true;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        
    }

    void FixedUpdate(){ 
        if(IsPlaying == true) {
            transform.Translate(Vector3.forward * velocity * Time.fixedDeltaTime * Input.GetAxis("Vertical"));
            transform.Translate(Vector3.right * velocity * Time.fixedDeltaTime * Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"));
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my problem I want to make a variable that will make me able to turn on and off the possibility to move but when I try to run this code it gives me this error:

**Assets\script\death.cs(18,13): error CS0120: An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'player_script.IsPlaying'**

I've tried to add public bool on the death script on line 18 but it just gives me those errors:

**Assets\script\death.cs(19,34): error CS1001: Identifier expected**

**Assets\script\death.cs(21,5): error CS1022: Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected**

**Assets\script\death.cs(22,1): error CS1022: Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected**

thank you every help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You are not referencing `player_script` in your `death` script. To get a reference to `player_script` in `death` script, initialize `player_script` variable in your `death` script

```
public player_script player_script_gameobject;
```

Now, in the inspector of the game object with the `death` script, a slot can be seen in the `death` script. Drag the game object with the `player_script` script into that slot. Now you have successfully referenced `player_script` in your `death` script and you can access its `public` variables.

Hence, now the `public` variable `IsPlaying` can be accessed and modified at line 18 as

```
player_script_gameobject.IsPlaying = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello and I'm glad you joined us. The `player_script` in death script actually calls the class type, while you need an instance of it that is your player. I think since you are a beginner it may be a little difficult to understand And better use the easier way. so add simple `static` keyword behind the `IsPlaying` variable to solve this problem.

```
public static bool IsPlaying = true;
```

Remember that the static variable is defined for the class, so do not use the player_script code for units other than the main player.